# Linking instances of two classes together

Tags: c#, constructor

Programming newbie here and I've been breaking my head over this for several hours now.

I can make a coordinate object but then I want to make a dot object that can access the coordinate fields from a Coordinate object. How do I "link" these two classes together? And do you have any recommendations for good YouTube videos that explain what I'm missing here? Thanks!

```
class Coordinate
{
    public int X { get; private set; } = 0;
    public int Y { get; private set; } = 0;
    public Coordinate(int x, int y)
    {
        x = X;
        y = Y;
    }        
}

class Dot
{
    public string color { get; set; }
    public Dot(string color, Dot dot)
    {
        this.Color = color;
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Coordinate coor1 = new Coordinate(2, 3);
        Dot dot1 = new Dot("Blue", coor1);        
    }
```

Comment: Just add a `Coordinate` member variable to `Dot`?

Comment: Also if it is not a typo the code that should initialize two properties in the Coordinate constructor is inverted. _X = x; Y = y;_ And Robot should be Dot

Answer (score 1):

Here is what you are searching for a "linking" your classes. In object-oriented programming this is called [composition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_over_inheritance).

That way you can use functionality and data of Coordinate-instance inside your Dot class.

```
class Coordinate
{
    public int X { get; private set; }
    public int Y { get; private set; }
    public Coordinate(int x, int y)
    {
        X = x;
        Y = y;
    }        
}

class Dot
{
    public Coordinate coord { get; private set; }
    public string color { get; set; }
    public Dot(string color, Coordinate coord)
    {
        this.color = color;
        this.coord = coord;

    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Coordinate coor1 = new Coordinate(2, 3);
        Dot dot1 = new Dot("Blue", coor1);
        Console.WriteLine(dot1.coord.X);        
    }
}
```

Note: I also fixed possible typo in Coordinate-constructor (setting X=x and Y=y..)

Comment: `public Robot` should be `public Dot`.

Comment: From comments above on the Q looks like it was in the original.

Comment: Thanks so far. One thing I want to achieve is being able to do              Console.WriteLine(dot1.Coordinate.X); , how can I do that?

Comment: I edited my answer: visibility is now so that new property can be read publicly but write only privately inside the class. Syntax for reading is: Console.WriteLine(dot1.coord.X)

Comment: No problem, happy to help! (please accept answer if satisfied) :)